# how do I find the value stored in array of object and console the key?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am trying to write a function that takes pokemon’s name as an argument and find out which all pokemon have that name in their “next_evolution” field

Consider the following JSON dataset -

visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json

my code for the said question:

```
var infoOfPokemon = function(nameOfPokemon, allPokemon) {
  for (x in allPokemon) {
    if (allPokemon[x].next_evolution &&
      allPokemon[x].next_evolution.includes(nameOfPokemon)) {
      console.log('pokemons found: ' + allPokemon[x].name)
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
}
var nameOfPokemon = prompt('enter the name of Pokemon')
infoOfPokemon(nameOfPokemon, pokemonData.pokemon)
```

my function isn't returning the name of pokemon that has its name in next_evolution field.

Comment: Are you missing return statement?

Comment: the only possible error could be in the if statement as .includes is not valid for an array of objects, as next_evolution is an array of objects.
so please suggest the possible ways to compare namOf Pokemon with the name key in next_evolution field.

Comment: As next evolution is an array, then you have to iterate it again on next_evolution object which is array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON object, next_evolution object is an array of Objects and it not populated always.

You were operating directly on the next_evolution field considering it as String array hence your include didn't work.

Below code is tedious but gives explanation of your wrong iteration

```
var infoOfPokemon = function(nameOfPokemon, allPokemon) {
    for (index in allPokemon) {
        var nextEvolutionObject=allPokemon[index].next_evolution;
      if (nextEvolutionObject){
          for(evolutionIndex in nextEvolutionObject){
              if(nextEvolutionObject[evolutionIndex].name===nameOfPokemon){
                  console.log("Pokemon found :"+nameOfPokemon);
              }
          }

      }
    }
  }
  var nameOfPokemon = prompt('enter the name of Pokemon');
  infoOfPokemon(nameOfPokemon, pokemonData.pokemon)
```

Comment: hey, your code works fine but it gives the same output every time. like "Ivysaur" even if I input 100 different pokemon name

Comment: var infoOfPokemon = function(nameOfPokemon, allPokemon) {
    for (index in allPokemon) {
        var nextEvolutionObject=allPokemon[index].next_evolution;
      if (nextEvolutionObject){
          for(evolutionIndex in nextEvolutionObject){
              if(nextEvolutionObject[evolutionIndex].name===nameOfPokemon){
                  console.log("Pokemon found :"+allPokemon[index].name);
              }
          }

      }
    }
  }
  var nameOfPokemon = prompt('enter the name of Pokemon')
  infoOfPokemon('nameOfPokemon', pokemonData.pokemon)
this edited code worked fine thanks

Comment: @SmAshhar, yeah for testing purpose, I wrote Ivysaur instead of number of Pokemon. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using  [**`some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)  and [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). That would make things easy for you

```
pokemonData.pokemon.filter(o=> o.next_evolution.some(e=> e.name === nameOfPokemon))
```

Comment: where should I use your code?
in if statement or like what?

Comment: after this line `var nameOfPokemon = prompt('enter the name of Pokemon')`